# How to host multiple web apps as a part of a single domain

Tags: iis, rewrite

I want to deploy multiple asp.net mvc applications under a single domain, but I am not sure what is the proper way to do it in IIS.

I want them to have the following urls

```
www.domain.com/something-from-app1
www.domain.com/something-from-app2
```

There are couple of options that I had in mind, but not sure would they actually work in practice.

Deploy each app as a subdomain and then do a rewrite

```
app1.domain.com/something to www.domain.com/something-from-app1
app2.domain.com/something to www.domain.com/something-from-app2
```

Deploy each app under a virtual folder of a domain and then do a rewrite

```
www.domain.com/site/app1/something to www.domain.com/something-from-app1
www.domain.com/site/app2/something to www.domain.com/something-from-app2
```

Both options are just pure theory, and I would like to know will both scenarios work as I explained abovre?

Answer (score 1):

All these options are possible. However, there's no reason for any rewriting, because you can also directly host the apps in the desired locations,

```
www.example.com/app1/something
www.example.com/app2/something
```

If you want to hide these, consider that the URLs should be different. Otherwise there's no way to distinguish which app should handle the request. Subdomains would be fine.

Comment: I have update my question, actually I want to hide the app1/app2 part of path and go directly to app directory structure. I dont know how to do that without rewrite. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Either method will work. If you want to go with the 2nd option while obfuscating the path, you can create a Virtual Directory in IIS. This can make it appear at the root, but is actually pointing elsewhere (like a shortcut/link).

Additional reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx

Edit: An option similar to Virtual Directories (but more app oriented), is to create (or convert those virtual directories into) Applications. That way you can assign them to their own Application Pools, segregate sessions from the root app (and each other), etc.